# How to dynamically render number of rows for a react table, Where my React devs at?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this table rendering this APP_DATA object. But I want to have the number of rows as a column (header left blank on purpose), how would i dynamically render the number next to each row?

bare in mind, since only "prt" and "cat" are arrays, you can only use Array methods on those.

i really appreciate any help

```js
const API_DATA = [
    {
        "bnd": "test brand 11",
        "url": "htttps://www.test.com/all-products11",
        "cnt": "UK",
        "prt": ['Perf. Supps'],
        "cat": ['Keto']
    },
    {
        "bnd": "test brand 12",
        "url": "htttps://www.test.com/all-products12",
        "cnt": "UK",
        "prt": ['Diet. Supps'],
        "cat": ['Gaming']
    },
 ]
 
 
 // table 
 
 return (
        <>    

        
        <TableBody >
          {filteredData(props.API_DATA,props.filters).map(row => (
            <TableRow  key={row.name}>
            <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}   align="center">{row.bnd}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}   align="center">{row.bnd}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}  align="center">{row.cnt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}  align="center">{row.prt.map((e) => <span style={{padding: "5px"}} key={e} >{`${e + ','}`}</span>)}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}  align="center">{row.cat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}}  align="center"><a href={row.url}>{row.url}</a></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>

        </>
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` method provide you the index as a second argument . since the index starts with `0` you can do `index + 1` . so that the rownum starts with `1` .

```
<TableBody >
{filteredData(props.API_DATA,props.filters).map((row, index) => (
  <TableRow  key={row.name}>
  <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left"}} align="center">{index + 1}</TableCell> 
     ..... 
  </TableRow>
))}
</TableBody>
```